# Can't pass params in URL to react component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass `params` in the URL to a React component, but doing so gives errors.
These are the errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

epoxy:68 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at epoxy:68:9
```

Screenshot of error messages:
[image: errors]

I get these errors if I navigate to the page `http://localhost:3000/project-details/epoxy`.

However, if I naviagte to `http://localhost:3000/project-details` then no errors.

But if I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/project-details/` (notice the slash at the end), then I get the same errors again.

Here is the relevant code:
**App.js:**

```
import { React } from 'react';
import AppRoute from '../components/route-components/Approute';

function App() {
  return (
   <AppRoute />
  );
}

export default App;
```

**AppRoute.js:**

```
function AppRoute() {

    return (
        < BrowserRouter >
            < Switch >
                < Route path = '/' exact component = { Home } />  
                < Route path = { `/project-details/:id` } component = { SingleProjectPage } /> 
                < Route path = { `/project-details` } component = { SingleProjectPage } />  
                < Route path='*' component = { ErrorPage }/> 
            </ Switch> 
        </ BrowserRouter>
    )
        
    
}
export default AppRoute;
```

**SingleProjectPage:**

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';

const SingleProjectPage = (props) =>{
    let data = sectionData.sectionTitle.singleProject;
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.match.params.id);
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }, [])
    return (
        <Fragment>
            hello
        </Fragment>

    )
}
export default SingleProjectPage;
```

I took over this project and it is already a massive project so I am having a hard time diagnosing the issue. It looks to me like this should just work, I am not seeing any issues. After reading other similar questions, it looks like the code may be trying to use `jQuery` before it is available to me, but why would the path `http://localhost:3000/project-details/` break the app just because of a forward slash at the end?

Any ideas? I can provide more code if needed.

EDIT: it even fails if I change the route to this:

```
{/* < Route path = { `/project-details/:id` } component = { SingleProjectPage } /> 
< Route path = { `/project-details` } component = { SingleProjectPage } />   */}
< Route path = { `/project-details/epoxy` } component = { SingleProjectPage } />
```

Its like I am unable to change that route in any way.

Comment: Are there any errors before your first `Unexpected token '<'`?

Comment: No, that is the very first error

Comment: As soon as you add a slash to your URL, the code will use the route `/project-details/:id`, where it's expecting an `id` value.

Comment: Thats true, but I get the same exact error if I do provide a value. There is something else causing this but I have no idea what.

Comment: Where are you importing jQuery?

Comment: I’m new to this and JQuery. I searched JQuery in the project and so many items pop up. Where is it usually or what can I search in my project to find it?

Comment: Any chance this could be a file extension issue? Some bundlers seem really strict when it comes to .js vs .jsx, and that’s naturally related to `<`

Comment: Are you saying I should try naming all the files in the question to .Jsx files?

Comment: @mcool Only the ones that have jsx tags in them

Comment: The error is `epoxy:68 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` but you didn't include this file... please include all relevant code in your question. My guess is you didn't import jquery in this `epoxy` file, so `$` is undefined. Jquery is a bit dated and since it has a fairly orthogonal approach to UI from React they don't generally work well together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the route works if I only have one forward slash in the path. No idea why. But for example, this will work:

```
< Route path = { `/epoxy` } component = { SingleProjectPage } />
```

But this will not:

```
< Route path = { `/project/epoxy` } component = { SingleProjectPage } />
```

Just having the extra path /`project` at the prefix breaks it.